# Wordpress filter with multiple parameters

Tags: wordpress, date, filter, args

I'm trying to set up a wordpress page in which there is a main section with upcoming events and a secondary section in which there are passed events.
I'm using this filter (located in functions.php) in order to switch upcoming and passed events:

```
// upcoming events
function listing_filter_function($date_args){
$date_args = array(
                    'post_type'   => 'evento',
                    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'meta_query'=> array(
                        array(
                          'key' => 'start_date',
                          'compare' => '>=',
                          'value' => date("Ymd"),
                          'type' => 'DATE'
                        )
                    ),
                );
return $date_args; } add_filter('listing_filter', 'listing_filter_function');

// events archive
function archive_filter_function($date_args){
$date_args = array(
                'post_type'   => 'evento',
                'meta_key' => 'start_date',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'meta_query'=> array(
                    array(
                      'key' => 'start_date',
                      'compare' => '<',
                      'value' => date("Ymd"),
                      'type' => 'DATE'
                    )
                ),
            );
return $date_args; } add_filter('archive_filter', 'archive_filter_function');
```

In this filter the events are sorted using the start date, but I would also need to check the end date to prevent events lasting more than one day from being show in the archive section after the first day
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the meta_query relation for this like this example

```
'meta_query'=> array(
'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'compare' => '>='
            'value' => date("Ymd"),
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'compare' => '<'
            'value' => date("Ymd"),
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    )
```

for the archive you can check if the end_date is smaller then today or equal or less (<=)

Edit to answer the Question in the comment, this was asked after marking the answer correct. Please note I'm not 100% on this as I'm readying mixed results about this method so if it works please let us know so I can update this to reflect the results

```
'meta_query'  => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'compare' => '>'
            'value' => date("Ymd"),
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'compare' => '<'
            'value' => date("Ymd"),
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'compare' => '>'
            'value' => date("Ymd"),
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, it has been useful for upcoming events, the only thing I had to do is replace AND with OR because there are events without an end date;
for the same reason it doesn't work with the archive,
if I use AND it only shows events that have an end_date,
if I use OR it also shows events whose start_date has passed.

How can i check if _start_date_ has passed and, if _end_date_ exists, check if it has passed? 

thank you

Comment: @Enrico I added a possible solution but I don't know if it will work there are mixed oppinions on this method working. [Source for the edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75079/nested-meta-query-with-multiple-relation-keys), and [source on developers.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

it finally works!
I've made some changes:

```
'meta_query'=> array('relation' => 'OR',
        array('relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'start_date',
                'compare' => '<',
                'value' => date("Ymd"),
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end_date',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        ),
        array('relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'start_date',
                'compare' => '<',
                'value' => date("Ymd"),
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end_date',
                'compare' => '<',
                'value' => date("Ymd"),
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
        ),
    ),
```